# Лексические ошибки в предложениях

Tags: лексика

**Прочитайте предложения из деловых бумаг. Найдите лексические ошибки, исправьте их.**

1. Вышеперечисленный металл требуется для изготовления нестандартного оборудования.
2. Помимо подписи, документы часто удостоверяют печатью.
3. Настоящим извещаем, что Ваше предложение о расформировании архива в настоящее время не может быть выполнено.
4. Препровождаем при сём акт на аварийное состояние вспомогательной станции.

**Возможные варианты:**

1. Вышеназванный металл требуется для изготовления нестандартного оборудования.
2. Часто, помимо подписи, документы удостоверяются печатью.
3. Настоящим извещаем, что Ваше предложение о расформировании архива в ближайшее время не может быть выполнено.
4. Направляем вам акт об аварийном состоянии вспомогательной станции.

Будьте добры, помогите.

Answer (score 3):

1. Ваш вариант верен: Вышеназванный металл требуется для изготовления нестандартного оборудования.
2. Кроме подписи, документы часто удостоверяются печатью.
3. Вы верно убрали повтор, но есть ещё лексическая несочетаемость - предложение не выполняют,а рассматривают, принимают  или реализовывают, выполняют распоряжения.
    Возможно так:
   Настоящим письмом извещаем, что Ваше распоряжение о расформировании архива в ближайшее время не может быть исполнено.

4.Ваш вариант приемлем, стилистический разнобой и устаревшие выражения Вы убрали : Направляем вам акт об аварийном состоянии вспомогательной станции.

Comment: В 4-м предложении, после редактирования смысл изменился. Там скорее *"Прилагаем при том акт..."*

Comment: Тогда уж "Акт об аварийном состоянии вспомогательной станции прилагается".

Answer (score 1):

Этот металл требуется для изготовления нестандартного оборудования.
Документы часто заверяют не только подписью, но и печатью.
По рассмотрении вашего предложения извещаем, что расформирование архива в настоящее время невозможно.
Прилагаем акт об аварийном состоянии вспомогательной станции.